# date.timezone configuration fails on OSX 10.11

Tags: php, apache

For a localhost environment I am trying to setup the default date in `/etc/php.ini`.

Running `$ php -i` shows `date.timezone => America/New_York => America/New_York`

`phpinfo()` is still giving me the "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings."

I've tried deleting and copying the `php.ini.default` and restarting apache multiple times.

Adding the `php.ini` file to a project folder also doesn't set a default value. But setting `date_default_timezone_set('ZONE')` works. I'd prefer to set it globally.

### Environment

- PHP Version 5.5.31
- Apache 2.4.18

`$ php --ini` results:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

`phpinfo()` results:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the right php.ini file to edit? Look inside the results of phpinfo() for the `Configuration File Path`. Command line and web server can use different php.ini files, so make sure to look at the right one.

Comment: @aynber Yep. The results - `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini`. It's the same path from running `phpinfo()`  `Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc`. But it does say "loaded config file: none"

Comment: What are the permissions on `/etc/php.ini`? maybe the user that Apache runs under (usually www-data) is unable to read it. That would explain why you get `Loaded Configuration File   (none)`

Comment: @dan08 `-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  69304 May 13 11:43 /etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I defined a `PHPIniDir` value for a local server address.

After removing that line, the default values loaded in again. Now I'm running into a different issue (per directory `ini` files), but defining the `date.timezone`'s default value has been resolved. Other settings can be overridden using the directory's `.htaccess`